# Does a group action always induce a quotient?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, normal-subgroups, equivariant-maps

Let $G$ be a group, let $X$ be a set on which $G$ acts (possibly non-faithfully).

I would be tempted to say the following:

> There exists a normal subgroup $K$ of $G$, such that:
>
> - $G/K$ acts faithfully (or freely? or both?) on $X$, and
> - The action of $G$ and of $G/K$ on $X$ are isomorphic.

Is this true? If yes, what is its relation to stabilizers? If no, are there conditions to require in order to make it true? Or is it simply false in general (for example, $K$ would depend always on the point of $X$)?

A reference would also be welcome, but please, for general sets (not modules).

Thanks!

Comment: What is the role of $\;X\;$ and of the action of $\;G\;$ on it in what you'd be tempted to say?

Comment: Ha, right! They come up in the rest of the work I'm doing...wait, let me rewrite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

The action can be written as a homomorphism $\phi : G \to S(X)$, where $S(X)$ is the symmetric group over $X$.
Now take $K$ as the kernel of $\phi$.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that was more or less what I was thinking. But the thing I'm missing is: if $K$ is trivial, how is the action? Free or faithful?

Comment: It is faithful then.